# Adding trail designs to windows cursor

Tags: mouse-cursor

I want to know if it's possible for me to have the same effect and desing this web page has but on my pc (the trail of the pointer), not in a webpage but in my desktop for example.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503699/open-a-outlook-new-mail-using-php-and-html

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: In Windows if you go to Control Panel>View by icons>Mouse>Pointer settings, there is a way to add pointer trails but is not customizable.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to modify the Windows cursor beyond the small selection of pre-designed cursors and trails in Windows.

It's possible you could write a plugin that does this, or find an existing utility that offers this. Custom cursors used to be a big thing in Windows theming. But with the changes in Windows 7, 8, and 10, many of the themable aspects of Windows have been limited.

However, the trails design of Windows cursors, as it is originally designed to aid in cursor visibility and not just for cool visual effect, does not behave in the way the trail behaves in that web page, and it is likely you'll need something other than a custom cursor design to get that precise behavior.